# python task: price in dollars and cents

Tags: python, python-3.x

As input, I have a number, price in dollars and cents (for example: 10.35) I need to print dollar and cents (based on above exmaple: 10 35). (input 10.09 - output 10 09 
I created the code:

```
from math import floor, trunc
a = float(input())
r = trunc(a)
k = trunc(a * 100)
k = (k % 100)
if k <= 9:
    print(r, "%02d" % (k,))
else:
    print(r, k)
```

However, when I test it on automatic tester, one of the conditions is not working. I am not able to see input in the test, please could you tell me where do I have mistake?

Comment: Your code seems to be working. You need to provide input value through the command line. Are you not doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test function not script. Problem probably caused by no correct test.

Try this:

```
from math import trunc


def to_new_format(price):
    dolar_part = trunc(price)
    cent_part = round(((price % 1) * 100), 3)
    return "%i %i" % (dolar_part, cent_part)


input_price = float(input())
print(to_new_format(input_price))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is a string `10.35` (as it seems to me) than you could also try the following (I know you were not asking this, but it might help nevertheless):

```
a = string(input())
b = a.split(".")
res = b[0] + " " + b[1]

print(res)
```

which outputs:

```
10 35
```